# Can CircleCI do unit/espresso testing for Android project?

Tags: android, circleci

we are using CircleCI for our Android project. I wonder whether CircleCI can support unit test/espresso test. I could not find too much useful information on internet.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, CircleCI can support running unit and espresso tests by configuring your circle.yml

## For Unit Tests

```
test
  ./gradlew test
```

## For Espresso Tests

Espresso tests are a little more involved because you need to run these tests on an android emulator.

```
test:
  pre:
  # start the emulator
  - emulator -avd circleci-android22 -no-audio -no-window:
    background: true
    parallel: true
  # wait for it to have booted
  - circle-android wait-for-boot
  # unlock the emulator screen
  - sleep 30
  - adb shell input keyevent 82

  override:
    # run tests against the emulator.
    - ./gradlew connectedAndroidTest -PdisablePreDex
```

Comment: I tried what you have suggested but I come across an error https://circleci.com/gh/adityam7/PopularMovies/21 is the link to my CircleCI build where its failing

Comment: Note for Unit Tests, from the docs:

_Testing Android Projects
Firstly: if you have a Gradle wrapper in the root of your repository, we’ll automatically run ./gradlew test._

https://circleci.com/docs/1.0/android/#testing-android-projects

Answer (score 1):

I got my CircleCI build to run both espresso and unit test below is my circle.yml file

```
general:
artifacts:
    - /home/ubuntu/PopularMovies/app/build/outputs/apk/

machine:
environment:
    ANDROID_HOME: /usr/local/android-sdk-linux

dependencies:
    override:
        - echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter tools,platform-tools,android-23,extra-android-m2repository,extra-google-m2repository,extra-google-google_play_services,extra-android-support
    - echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter build-tools-23.0.3

test:
  override:

  # perform unit tests
  - ./gradlew tesMockDebugUnitTest
  # Save test reports
  - mkdir -p $CIRCLE_TEST_REPORTS/reports/unit-tests
  - cp -avr app/build/reports/tests/mockDebug/ $CIRCLE_TEST_REPORTS/reports/unit-tests
  - mkdir -p $CIRCLE_TEST_REPORTS/junit/
  - find . -type f -regex ".*/build/test-results/mockDebug/.*xml" -exec cp {} $CIRCLE_TEST_REPORTS/junit/ \;

  # start the emulator
  - emulator -avd circleci-android22 -no-audio -no-window:
      background: true
      parallel: true
  # wait for it to have booted
  - circle-android wait-for-boot
  # unlock the emulator screen
  - sleep 30
  - adb shell input keyevent 82
  # run tests against the emulator.
  - ./gradlew connectedMockDebugAndroidTest -PdisablePreDex
  # Copying the test reports
  - mkdir -p $CIRCLE_TEST_REPORTS/reports/functional-tests
  - cp -avr app/build/reports/androidTests/connected/flavors/MOCK/ $CIRCLE_TEST_REPORTS/reports/functional-tests
```

You can view my CircleCI build at https://circleci.com/gh/adityam7/PopularMovies/25

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Put following in your circle.yml, then at least your unit tests should run (I don't have espresso tests in my project yet)

`test:
  override:
    - export TERM="dumb"; if [ -e ./gradlew ]; then ./gradlew test;else gradle test;fi
    - cp -r app/build/test-results/* $CIRCLE_TEST_REPORTS`

Last line copies your test result so CircleCI can analyze them. Be sure to provide proper path to /build directory

Refer to CircleCI documentation for more information and for tests on running emulator - https://circleci.com/docs/android

Answer (score 0):

I am running Android UI tests on CircleCI MacOS executor. Here is my
configuration:

```
version: 2
reference:
  ## Constants
  gradle_cache_path: &gradle_cache_path
    gradle_cache-{{ checksum "build.gradle" }}-{{ checksum  "app/build.gradle" }}
  workspace: &workspace
    ~/src
  ## Configurations
  android_config: &android_config
    working_directory: *workspace
    macos:
      xcode: "9.4.0"
    shell: /bin/bash --login -eo pipefail
    environment:
      TERM: dumb
      JVM_OPTS: -Xmx3200m
  ## Cache
  restore_gradle_cache: &restore_gradle_cache
    restore_cache:
      key: *gradle_cache_path
  save_gradle_cache: &save_gradle_cache
    save_cache:
      key: *gradle_cache_path
      paths:
        - ~/.gradle

  ## Dependency Downloads
  download_android_dependencies: &download_android_dependencies
    run:
      name: Download Android Dependencies
      command: ./gradlew androidDependencies

jobs:
  ui_test:
    <<: *android_config
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Setup environment variables
          command: |
            echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/opt/node@8/bin:${HOME}/.yarn/bin:${HOME}/${CIRCLE_PROJECT_REPONAME}/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/share/android-sdk/tools/bin"' >> $BASH_ENV
            echo 'export ANDROID_HOME="/usr/local/share/android-sdk"' >> $BASH_ENV
            echo 'export ANDROID_SDK_HOME="/usr/local/share/android-sdk"' >> $BASH_ENV
            echo 'export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT="/usr/local/share/android-sdk"' >> $BASH_ENV
            echo 'export QEMU_AUDIO_DRV=none' >> $BASH_ENV
            echo 'export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/Home' >> $BASH_ENV
      - run:
          name: Install Android sdk
          command: |
            HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1 brew tap homebrew/cask
            HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1 brew cask install android-sdk
      - run:
          name: Install emulator dependencies
          command: (yes | sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-26" "extras;intel;Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager" "build-tools;26.0.0" "system-images;android-26;google_apis;x86" "emulator" --verbose) || true
      - *restore_gradle_cache
      - *download_android_dependencies
      - *save_gradle_cache
      - run: avdmanager create avd -n Pixel_2_API_26 -k "system-images;android-26;google_apis;x86" -g google_apis -d "Nexus 5"
      - run:
          name: Run emulator in background
          command: /usr/local/share/android-sdk/tools/emulator @Pixel_2_API_26 -skin 1080x2066 -memory 2048 -noaudio
          background: true
      - run:
          name: Run Tests
          command: ./gradlew app:connectedAndroidTest
```

https://gist.github.com/DoguD/58b4b86a5d892130af84074078581b87

https://github.com/c2mInc/Circle-CI-Instrumentation-Tests-for-Android

I hope it helps